# if statement using innerText not working with element idea buttons

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to trigger an audio file when a button is hovered and has a specific number displayed it will play a specific audio file.

The first code does not work for me.
The second code works but not correctly and some how doesnt take into consideration what is being displayed on the button.

//First-Code - Assigns answer-buttons with an event listener

```
document.getElementById('answer-buttons').addEventListener("mouseover", answerHoverButtonAudio);
//Button Function to call answerHoverButtonAudio
function answerHoverButtonAudio() {

    if (document.getElementById('answer-buttons').innerText == ('1')) {
        var audio = document.getElementById('Number-1')
        audio.play();
    }
}
```

//Second-Code - This code below triggers the audio but does it no matter what text is showing on the button somehow.

//Assigns answer-buttons with an event listener

```
document.getElementById('answer-buttons').addEventListener("mouseover", answerHoverButtonAudio);
//Button Function to call answerHoverButtonAudio
function answerHoverButtonAudio() {

    if (answerButtonsElement.innerText.includes('1')) {
        var audio = document.getElementById('Number-1')
        audio.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: *//First-Code - Assigns answer-buttons with an event listener* This version checks whether `document.getElementById('answer-buttons').innerText` equals exactly "1" or 1 or true. *//Second-Code - This code below triggers the audio but does it no matter what text is showing on the button somehow.* This indicates that "1" is always included in `answerButtonsElement.innerText`. Yet it is impossible to tell with the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event passed via mouseevent listener which can check innerText to play particular audio.

code sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-hypatia-j76ggx?file=/src/index.js

```js
const answerHoverButtonAudio = (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.innerText.includes("1")) {
    debugger;
    var audio = document.getElementById("Number-1");
    audio.play();
  }
};

document
  .getElementById("answer-buttons")
  .addEventListener("mouseover", answerHoverButtonAudio);
```

```html
<div id="answer-buttons">1</div>

<audio controls id="Number-1">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
```

Comment: Thank you @prograk I tried this code and displayed 4 buttons however no matter what text is showing in the button, it still plays the same audio. I want it see the text in the button, and then play the audio for that text.
For instance, if the text button has '1' or '2' or '3' I have a separate audio file for each of those.